# One of Multiple Tasks Operated by Button Won't Execute

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

I'm having problems with one of multiple tasks being executed by a button. The button executes two of three tasks (hides them upon `.(click)`), except the last one, a text-blinking javascript function. I can't see what can be possibly wrong! The same syntax to hide the text before it is the same syntax used to hide the next one, but for some reason it won't hide it (the blinking text). Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}

.text1{
 padding-left: 15px;
 color: white; 
 font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
 width: 250px;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 10px;
}


.text2{
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").on('click',function(){
      $("p").hide();
      $(".text1").hide();
      $(".text2").hide();
      $('body').css("background", "black");  

    });

    var element = $(".text2");
    var shown = true;
    setInterval(toggle, 500);

    function toggle() {
     if(shown) {
        element.hide();
     } else {
        element.show();
     }
    shown = !shown;
  }


});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="text1">
  PRESS BUTTONS BELOW
  </div>
  <div class="text2">-- : --</div>  
  <button class="btn1">online</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide `.text2` clear the `setInterval` using `clearInterval`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").on('click', function() {
    $("p").hide();
    $(".text1").hide();
    $(".text2").hide(function() {
      clearInterval(x)
    });
    $('body').css("background", "black");

  });

  var element = $(".text2");
  var shown = true;
  var x = setInterval(toggle, 500);

  function toggle() {
    if (shown) {
      element.hide();
    } else {
      element.show();
    }
    shown = !shown;
  }


});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
}

.text1 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.text2 {
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text1">
  PRESS BUTTONS BELOW
</div>
<div class="text2">-- : --</div>
<button class="btn1">online</button>
```

Comment: thanks so much! So `clearInterval(x)` essentially releases the loop that keeps `#text2` blinking? Correct?