# Solution for Javascript Multi-tasked Buttons Not Working Correctly in CodePen

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, clearinterval

I created, with some help, some javascript code to enable multiple operations to be accomplished when I press some buttons in my web app. It is working perfectly with the solution provided at the following link: [One of Multiple Tasks Operated by Button Won't Execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971674/one-of-multiple-tasks-operated-by-button-wont-execute/48971711#48971711,(answer) provided by brk), but it is not working when I import the code into my CodePen text editor. There are three buttons, "online, offline, and all, which are upon being pressed, supposed to

1. switch the blue screen to black
2. hide the text that says, "PRESS BUTTONS BELOW"
3. hide the blinking **--:--** symbol

However, when I press the "**online**", "**offline**", and "**all**" buttons, it almost seems as if nothing happens, because **there is a short delay**. Why does this delay happen? Also, the blinking **--:--** symbol **doesn't terminate blinking** as it should...can you tell me why this is? Thanks so much in advance for the help!
See CodePen link here: https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/mXMqGV

Here is my javascript code:

```
var twitchTvStreamers;
var loaded = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

//GET TWITCH TV STREAMERS' STATUS AND API CALL

twitchTvStreamers=["FreeCodeCamp", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

//OUT OF ALL THE TWITCH TV STREAMERS IN A TWITCH TV ARRAY FIND THOSE 8 STREAMERS LISTED

});

//filter online offline and all
var filterchannel = filterch => { 
  if(!loaded)
  {
    for(channel of twitchTvStreamers){
      getChannelInfo(channel, filterch);
    }
  }


  else
    {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.display-output-here div').each(function(idx, item) {
          if($(item).hasClass(filterch))
            {
              $(item).show();
            }
          else
            {
              $(item).hide();
            }
        });
      }, 100);
    }

    if(!loaded)
  {
    for(channel of twitchTvStreamers){
      getChannelInfo(channel, filterch);
    }
  }

    {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.text1 div').each(function(idx, item) {
          if($(item).hasClass(filterch))
            {
              $(item).hide();
            }

        });
      }, 100);
    }

};//end of var filterChannel

$('button').click(function(e) {
 filterchannel(e.target.id);

})

var getChannelInfo = (channel, filterch) => { 
    loaded = true;
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + channel)
    .done(function(info) {
        console.log(channel);
        if (info.stream === null) {
          appendInfo(channel,'offline',filterch);
        }
        else {
          appendInfo(channel,'online', filterch);
        }

    });
}
var appendInfo = (channel,target, filterch) => {
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/' + channel)
        .done( function(ch){
            channelID = ch.display_name;
            channelLogo = ch.logo;
            channelUrl = ch.url;
            streamContent = ch.content;
            $('.display-output-here').append('<div class="' + target + ' all">'+channel+' is '+target);
            if(twitchTvStreamers[twitchTvStreamers.length - 1] === channel) {
              filterchannel(filterch);
            }
        });    


//BUTTONS OPERATIONS (ALL BUTTONS TARGETED BY USING CLASS THEY COME UNDER)
$(".user-status").on('click', function() {
    $(".text1").hide(); 
    $(".text2").hide(function() {
      clearInterval(x);
    });
    $('.display-output-here').css("background", "black");
    $('.TV-screen').css("background", "black");

  });

  var element = $(".text2");
  var shown = true;
  var x = setInterval(toggle, 500);

  function toggle() {
    if (shown) {
      element.hide();
    } else {
      element.show();
    }
    shown = !shown;
  }

}

//make part of video-screen text blink 
var element = $(".text2");
var shown = true;
setInterval(toggle, 500);

function toggle() {
    if(shown) {
        element.hide();
        shown = false;
    } else {
        element.show();
        shown = true;
    }
}

//share-links code:
$('.Linkedinbutton').click(function() {
  var shareurl = $(this).data('shareurl');
  window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/mXMqGV/' + escape(shareurl) + '&title=' + document.title + '&source=SourceTitle&target=new');
  return false;
});

//Facebook  
 var facebookShare = document.querySelector('[data-js="Facebookbutton"]');

facebookShare.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var facebookWindow = window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + document.URL, 'facebook-popup', 'height=350,width=600');
  if(facebookWindow.focus) { facebookWindow.focus(); }
    return false;
}

/*
//user status button operations


*/
//search bar operation
$("#searchStreamers").on("keypress",function(e){
   var typeStreamer = $('input').val();
     if(e.which===13){
       $('input').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
         });
        }
    });
```

Comment: [Cross Origin Ressource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)... Good reading. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, this has nothing to do with a solution to the problem I posted

Comment: Okay... The issue is about a code WORKING.. But not on CodePen,.. So that obvious issue out leaves what? Have you look at network tab in the dev tools? I also notice a correct access to anonymous CodePen users, but a *«Oops! Looks like you got logged out. You can log in here.»* error for logged in users. I don't know.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, oh ok! I will check that out. But CORS shouldn't affect non-API calling javascript, I don't think? Will do some more troubleshooting though...

Comment: CORS affect ajax requests... So `$.post()`, `$.get()`, `$.ajax()` and `$.getJSON()` can be affected. API or not is not the question. (as of my best knowledge).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, yeah exactly, that's what I know....my code issues aren't to do with those....it's do with some basic javascript code that isn't working in my CodePen the same way it is working in the Stack Overflow solution provided by a commentor...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, would you mind showing me what the problem is? I have to press the buttons twice instead of once for the function to work? Why is that? And I can't get the blinking symbol to stop blinking.